# In C++ for the use of arrays within functions, where data is entered into arrays from a .txt file using ifstream

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function, fstream

First time posting here. The question asks to use functions to calculate and out put into a table a payroll with gross, netpay and the like as well as output a condition into a text file. However my issue is with the functions refusing to loop when I use arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>//File stream
#include <string> //For use with string variables
#include <iomanip>//For use with formatting

double hoursworked[6],hourlyrate[6];
int i;

using namespace std;


double gross_fun(double hourlyrate[], double hoursworked[],int &numofelements) 

{
    double overtime[6];
    double gross[6];

    for(i=0; i<=5; i++){
        if (hoursworked[i] > 40){ 
                overtime[i] = 1.5*hourlyrate[i] * (hoursworked[i]-40); //Overtime is 1.5 times hourly rate
                    gross[i]=overtime[i]+(40*hourlyrate[i]);

            }

    else
        gross[i]= hourlyrate[i]  * hoursworked[i];


return gross[i];
}
}

double taxes_fun(double gross[], int &numofelements) 
{
    double taxes;

    for(i=0; i<=5; i++){

        taxes = .1 * gross[i]; 

    return taxes;
}
}

double SS_fun( double gross[], int &numofelements) 
    {
        double social;


        for(i=0; i<=5; i++){
            social = .05 * gross[i]; 
        return social;
    }
}

double netpay_fun(double gross[], double tax[], double social[], int &numofelements) 
    {
        double netpay;

        for(i=0; i<=5; i++){
        netpay= gross[i] - (tax[i] + social[i]); //Resultant net pay given when taxes and security are subtracted
        return netpay;
        }
    }


double taxes(double tax[], int &numofelements);
double social_security (double social[], int &numofelements);
double netpay_fun  (double netpay[], int &numofelements);
double gross_fun(double hourlyrate[], double hoursworked[], int &numofelements);

int main () 
{
    ifstream inFile; //To read .txt file
    inFile.open ("input.txt");

        if (inFile.fail()){ 
        cerr << "Error Opening File" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int EmpNum[6];//Employee Number
    int i = 0;    //Counter
    double gross[6],taxes[6],socia[6],netpay[6],moneytopay[6];
    double overtime[6],hoursworked[6],hourlyrate[6],social[6],totalnetpay = 0.0f;
    char paytype[6];
    string firstname[6],lastname[6];
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed; //Set double values to two decimal places

    (inFile>>EmpNum[i]>>firstname[i]>>lastname[i]>>hoursworked[i]>>hourlyrate[i]>>paytype[i]){
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
        gross[i]=gross_fun(hourlyrate, hoursworked, i); 
        taxes[i] = taxes_fun(gross, i);
        social[i] = SS_fun (gross, i);
        netpay[i] = netpay_fun  (gross, taxes, social, i);
        totalnetpay=totalnetpay+netpay[i];      


        }
    }


    cout << setw(6)  << "EmpNo"<< setw(13) << "First Name"<< setw(13)  << "Last Name"<< setw(8)  << "Gross";
    cout << setw(8)  << "Tax"<< setw(8)  << "SS"<< setw(10)  << "Net Pay"<< setw(9)  << " Payment Type";

    for(i=0;i<6;i++){

        cout << setw(5)  <<EmpNum[i]<< setw(11) <<firstname[i]<<setw(14)  <<lastname[i]<< setw(11)  << gross[i]<< setw(8)  << taxes[i];
        cout << setw(9)  << social[i]<< setw(8)  << netpay[i]<< setw(7)  << paytype[i]<< endl;
    }

    cout<<"\nSum of netpay: "<<totalnetpay;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please present an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: do you get an error message?

Comment: No, but it only uses the first line of input in the calculations. [link](http://i.imgur.com/Zv2cIjv.png)  Here is a screen of the text input file [link](http://i.imgur.com/VW8ZBAI.png)

Comment: Your functions are not "refusing to loop", but you have the `return` inside the body of the loop. Thus you return after the first execution of the loops.

Comment: @Michael Properly formatting your code would be helpful for yourself and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple, you have put you `return` statement inside your `for` loop. Just move it out.

```
double gross_fun(double hourlyrate[], double hoursworked[],int &numofelements) //Function to determine gross salary

{
    double overtime[6];
    double gross[6];
    double total = 0.0;

    for(i=0; i<=5; i++){
        if (hoursworked[i] > 40){ //Calculating gross salary if hours worked greater than 40
                overtime[i] = 1.5*hourlyrate[i] * (hoursworked[i]-40); //Overtime is 1.5 times hourly rate
                    gross[i]=overtime[i]+(40*hourlyrate[i]);

            }

    else
        gross[i]= hourlyrate[i]  * hoursworked[i]; //Calculating gross salary if no overtime is done

// remove here
}
return // something
}
```

You have done the same thing inside all your functions. If you want to return an array, i suggest you pass it in the parameters and return void. or return an array.

Comment: It's giving me 0 for all of my values, can you explain what you mean by pass the parameters and return void?

Comment: You add an argument in the parameter list of the function that is here only to be written into, not read. Something like that, in your case: `double gross_fun(double hourlyrate[], double hoursworked[], double gross[])`. And where you return was you write nothing, you have replaced your local variable `gross` by a parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much, just can you tell me why it's outputting either the first or last line of calculations incorrectly. For i=0;i<=5 and changing this in anyway either crashes the program or returns wrong values

Comment: I can't say for sure but i see two other problems in your code. The first is that after you have set the precision in your `main()` you read only one line. Don't you have forgotten the `while` key before `(inFile>>...`? Also, what is the size of your file? Sometimes you put 5, sometimes 6, you should define a `const unsigned int SIZE = 6` or something and only use that variable afterwards. Can't say much more for now.